# Spring MVC: mapping multiple nested properties

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC, excuse me if this has been answered before

I have the following request `data.test=test&data.rating=4&data.comments=test` My model object is

```
class Resp {
   Data data;
}
class Data {
    String test;
    String rating;
    String comments;
}
```

I am using `@ModelAttribute` and every thing is working fine.

My problem is that the properties of the data class are variable. Both number of properties and names of properties are dynamic, it will change at runtime. I tried different approaches like creating `setData(Map<String, String)` in Resp class. Nothing helped.

Thanks in advance

**Update:**
Sorry forgot to mention earlier, Good or bad, I am using Domain objects as my JPA Entities

Comment: how come your class variables are changing. Are you using reflection.

Comment: The number of properties will be changing. For example the request can be `data.test=test&data.rating=4&data.comments=test` or `data.abc=4&data.xyz=test` and so on. The same code should be able to serve both the cases

Comment: Use a `Map` in your `Resp` class instead of a `Data` class. Make sure you have appropriate getters/setters for it.

Comment: Tried that. Resp.data is initialized to `LinkedHashMap` but it does not contain any data

Answer (score 0):

You can simply take HashMap as request or response in Spring MVC. Only change is instead of getting paramName as field in object , you will get as key in Map. Similarly it works with Map in Response

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/testUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Map<String,String> test(
        @RequestBody Map<String,String> requestMap) {
```

Comment: Yes that is the workaround I am using now. But it has a couple of problems. Validation and populating the model object